# Search Error on new SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: search, 2013, sharepoint-search

When I do a search on any search box on my SharePoint site, I'm getting no search results. Even when the item I'm searching on is on the same page as the search. Looking in the error logs, the following errors show up for this correlation id:

---

Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://OurSPSite.com:80/sites/ESearchCenter/Pages/default.aspx/results.aspx?k=How%20To)). Parent No
Name=Request (GET:http://OurSPSite.com:80/sites/ESearchCenter/Pages/default.aspx/results.aspx?k=How%20To)   0a4a269c-123d-1090-3fc7-fa9b08d707bc
Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|specpro\user.name, ClaimsCount=27    0a4a269c-123d-1090-3fc7-fa9b08d707bc
UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres... 0a4a269c-123d-1090-3fc7-fa9b08d707bc
...)
Leaving Monitored Scope (PostResolveRequestCacheHandler). Execution Time=15.7365    0a4a269c-123d-1090-3fc7-fa9b08d707bc
Setting [Display] as the FormContext.FormMode for the current page  0a4a269c-123d-1090-3fc7-fa9b08d707bc
Culture Not Found 'ui-ui'.  0a4a269c-123d-1090-3fc7-fa9b08d707bc
Setting [Display] as the FormContext.FormMode for the current page  0a4a269c-123d-1090-3fc7-fa9b08d707bc
Setting [Display] as the FormContext.FormMode for the current page  0a4a269c-123d-1090-3fc7-fa9b08d707bc
Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002  0a4a269c-123d-1090-3fc7-fa9b08d707bc
SPRequest.GetMetadataForUrl: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-3228743725-162544756-4102905824-7609, AppPrincipalName= ,bs
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002),

CreatePageFromUrlNoUpperCase failed with FileNotFoundException. Url = '/sites/ESearchCenter/Pages/default.aspx/results.asp
Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002  0a4a269c-123d-1090-3fc7-fa9b08d707bc
SPRequest.GetMetadataForUrl: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-3228743725-162544756-4102905824-7609, AppPrincipalName= ,bs
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

---

This SharePoint site is a new install. Search has never worked on it yet. I have configured the search application and crawl as recommended by Microsoft. No errors show up in the crawl logs. The search application topology has green check marks for all server names.

This error happens when I do a simple search on content from one of my SharePoint sites. For example, in this case, I entered 'How To' in the Search box on a SharePoint page that had a link labeled as "How To Doc's". I'm getting the same errors with other similar searches on page text.

I've tried searching on several of the errors above and found nothing similar to this situation. Any ideas on why search is still returning no results? I would appreciate any information you could provide.

Comment: We have closed this for now as it isn't really answerable in its current form. Please edit the error message or reduce it to the salient parts somehow so that there is a chance somebody will try to answer it. If you flag it for moderator attention when you have done this we can get the question re-opened. Thanks.

Comment: Re-opened. Thanks for editing the question. Hope you get an answer.

Comment: There is nothing in the log indicating that there is a search error. Is the search service in the web application service association? Have you tried calling the REST search api? If that does not help try increase the verbosity of the uls log - there has to be something in it...

Comment: Hi Max. Thanks for responding. Yes, I did set up the search service application in the service application and it shows up in the "Manage Service Applications" list. I'll try your recommendations and let you know if something works. Thanks again.

Comment: Max, I increased the log verbosity and received an error I had not seen before. The message was: "97qu Verbose   SQM: Datapoint id 6693 marked as Increment datapoint. 4fab269c-e208-1090-3fc7-ffe15110cc0b" I did a Google search on that message, but none of the errors were related to search issues. I'm not sure how to call the REST Search api in SharePoint. Do you know of any tutorials for that? I'm familiar with REST, I've just never used it in a real world scenario before. I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: The searches I've done on the error messages I'm getting also seem to be unrelated to search. Based on what I've read, there may be problems with my service account. Still working on it. ..

Comment: We ended up tearing down the site and starting from scratch. We were not able to get Search working.

Comment: @hcShare Have you been able to get Search working in your new environment? I am having the same problem you describe in this question.  Any additional info you have would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: I actually never got search working with the above topology. We set up another SharePoint farm and configured it differently. Someone else set up search for this one and search does work. However, the SP topology for the original SP farm above was a two tier. This new SP topology is a one tier. We do not expect much traffic. Wish I could be more helpful, but my other projects started piling up, so I had to move on.

Comment: Please post here if you do find a solution. I may need it in the future if people here start using SharePoint more. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We eventually got search working by clearing the configuration cache. Here is the article with detailed information about this process:

Perform the below steps on all the servers in the farm.

1. Stop the Timer service.
   Start -> services.msc -> SharePoint Timer Service (SPTimerV4) -> Stop
2. Browse to %SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\GUID
   Note: The Program Data folder is a hidden file.
   There could be more than 2 folders in this location.
3. Open the folder named as GUID’s with ‘-’ (dashed filename for the folder).
   Example - 1f8c67d2-2cd9-4196-ab1a-d1a2daed2cc8
4. Arrange the files by Type. You would find several xml files and a file named cache.ini.
5. Delete all the xml files, and keep the cache.ini (DO NOT DELETE THIS FILE - cache.ini).
6. Reset cache.ini. If you open this file, you will find a number like this – 3400261. Change the value in cache.ini to 1.
7. Start the Timer service.
   Start -> services.msc -> SharePoint Timer Service (SPTimerV4) -> Start.
8. Note: The file system cache is re-created after you perform this procedure. Make sure that you perform this procedure on all servers in the server farm.
9. Make sure that the Cache.ini file in the GUID folder now contains its previous value. For example, make sure that the value of the Cache.ini file is not 1.
10. Check in the GUID folder to make sure that the xml files are repopulating. This may take a bit of time.

Hope this helps someone else too.

Comment: Please do not post link only answers, add some major steps from the link instead. If the link breaks your answer will be of no help to future readers

Answer (score 0):

The problem turns out to be not so rare.
To clarify the issue: In my case **search results always returned an error rather than no results, but the logs were identical as listed above.**
Elsewhere I’ve read that errors / warnings associated with “UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.” are benign.
The actual problem starts with “**Culture Not Found 'ui-ui'**”. If you happened to use a culture different than en-US anywhere (or even your browser decided to do it on your behalf), install appropriate language pack. This will also involve reconfiguring and restarting services, including search services, performed automatically at the end of the installation.
This is not enough, however. You also need to reset the search index.
The exact steps I’ve taken are: go to Central Administration, Search application. First, disable continuous crawl (if enabled) in your Content Sources. Then, reset the search index (Index Reset). It takes a while.
At this point you can check if it helped – if you try to search for something, search results won’t return anything but the search itself won’t fail.
Finally, perform full crawl and re-enable continuous crawl.
In my case it helped. 
 Hope it will also help someone.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I've never seen a "Culture Not Found" error and we don't use multiple languages where I work. If I do see that error, at least I'll know what to do.